# Can't figure out async function call

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a UISearchController to find friends on my app. To populate the array which the search controller is filtering, I'm getting my users' document IDs from Firestore. This uses an asynchronous method getDocuments. I'm trying to use a dispatch group so that my code still runs in the desired order, but it's not working. Here is my function:

```
func setAllUsers(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var temp = [String]()
        
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        FirestoreService.db.collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error accessing user collection: \(err)")
            } else {
                
                var counter = 0
                
                for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    counter += 1
                    print("Counter: \(counter)")
                    temp.append(doc.documentID)
                }
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(UserService.getUserArray(uids: temp))
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the call in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setAllUsers { (users) in
            self.allUsers = users
        }

        print("Number of users in Firestore: \(allUsers.count)")
}
```

When I run the code, I see this in the console:
Number of users in Firestore: 0
Counter: 1
Counter: 2
Counter: 3

How do I fix the order here?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix the order here?

Very easy, put the line into the closure, it contains the *asynchronous* code.

```
setAllUsers { (users) in
    self.allUsers = users
    print("Number of users in Firestore: \(self.allUsers.count)")
}
```

And you are misusing `DispatchGroup`, it's not needed

```
func setAllUsers(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
   
    var temp = [String]()
    FirestoreService.db.collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error accessing user collection: \(err)")
        } else {
            
            var counter = 0
            
            for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                counter += 1
                print("Counter: \(counter)")
                temp.append(doc.documentID)
            }
           completion(UserService.getUserArray(uids: temp))
        }
        
    }        
}
```

Comment: Does this mean for my search controller to access the allUsers array, all my other viewDidLoad code has to go in the closure as well?

Comment: Yes, the closure is executed after `viewDidLoad` has exited.

Comment: I just tried this fix and it still printed Number of users in Firestore: 0, then the counter increments. With this structure of code, the completion(UserService.getUserArray(uids: temp)) is running before the code in the getDocument completion block, so the completion block is called with an empty temp array.

Comment: I don't know what `UserService.getUserArray` does. If it's also asynchronous you have to pass the completion object and call it in there.

Comment: I realized my getUserArray isn't doing what I thought it was. I'm going to work on fixing that first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it inside the closure. Also, you don't need the `DispatchGroup`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setAllUsers { (users) in
            self.allUsers = users
            print("Number of users in Firestore: \(allUsers.count)")
            self.tableView.reloadData() // reload the view you're trying to populate with users here.
        }
}
```